# Hiding an element doesn't redraw page correctly in IE8 if the parent elements have a specific combination of display types

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a problem when hiding/showing certain elements in IE8. If an element with `display:inline-block` has any child (including nested children) with `display:block`, then any child of that element has problems when hiding/showing. The page does not redraw correctly, and other elements position do not change to reflect the newly hidden/shown elements.

The minimal markup that shows the problem is below. In the example, when you click 'Clickable element', then the three divs directly below are hidden. However, the Footer Div does not change position - a large gap is left. If you do something to force a page redraw, such as selecting all text on the page, then the footer jumps to the correct position.

Something similar happens when showing the elements. Instead of the footer div being pushed to the bottom, it is overlapped by the newly shown elements.

```
<div style="display:inline-block">
    <div>
    <!-- Any number of other HTML elements -->
        <div style="display:block">
            <div class = "clickable" >Clickable element.</div>
            <div class = "toggleable">Hideable element 1.</div>
            <div class = "toggleable">Hideable element 2.</div>
            <div class = "toggleable">Hideable element 3.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div>Footer Div</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.clickable').click(function(){
        $('.toggleable').toggle();
    });
</script>
```

I've been trying to break this down for a fair while now, and I'm almost certain that I've got the minimal problem down (`inline-block` element followed by `block` element, and perform a show/hide on a child element). Has anybody encountered this before - or any suggestions on how to work around this?

Comment: adding 'position:relative' to the target element often fixes this

Comment: That doesn't seem to help any, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick.  As the answer below states, inline-block isn't supported in older browsers and shows some quirky behaviour in certain versions of IE8.  I've remembered this fix from something I did a while back, but I'm sorry, I can't give you a full explanation as to why this is happening.  Anyhow, add a float to your main div, and clear your footer and, fingers crossed, it should work.

```
<div style="display:inline-block;float:left">
    <div>
    <!-- Any number of other HTML elements -->
        <div class="div-2" style="display:block">
            <div class = "clickable" >Clickable element.</div>
            <div class = "toggleable">Hideable element 1.</div>
            <div class = "toggleable">Hideable element 2.</div>
            <div class = "toggleable">Hideable element 3.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div style="clear:left">Footer Div</div>
```

Comment: That seems to fix it, thanks. Basically we're using a `float:left` to force an `inline` element to behave like an `inline-block` one, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be working fine in here... But note that IE8 have some problems rendering jquery, and the css property 'inline-block' is not really supported by old browser versions (ie7, doesn't work, ie8, i'm not sure). Try adding the "zoom:1;" fix to the css of your tags that have the inline-block going on. Hope that helps somehow.